# How to use a glyph in TextBox placeholder

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

How can a glyph be used as part of a placeholder in a `TextBox` like the one used in the Settings app? I want to be able to use the string resource too. `x:Uid="FindASetting"` didn't work.

**Expected result**

[image]

**Current result**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to use a glyph in TextBox placeholder

For this requirement, we need edit the  `TextBox` style, and find  `PlaceholderTextContentPresenter` `TextBlock` control remove default text property and the two `Runs` like the following.

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
    Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
    IsHitTestVisible="False"
    TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
    TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
    >
    <Run Text="PlaceholderText" />
    <Run FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE939;" />
</TextBlock>
```

**Update**

Complete style

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
            <Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarContextFlyout}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarSelectionFlyout}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Grid
                                                    x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                    Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                    >
                                                    <TextBlock
                                                        x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                        FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                        FontSize="12"
                                                        FontStyle="Normal"
                                                        Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}"
                                                        Text="&#xE10A;"
                                                        />

                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>

                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>

                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                        To="0"
                                                                        Duration="0"
                                                                        />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="{ThemeResource TextBoxTopHeaderMargin}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                FontWeight="Normal"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                />
                            <Border
                                x:Name="BorderElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"
                                MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                                CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                                />
                            <ScrollViewer
                                x:Name="ContentElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                />
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
                                TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                                >
                                <Run Text="PlaceholderText" />
                                <Run FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE939;" />
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Button
                                x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                MinWidth="34"
                                Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                />
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="DescriptionPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                x:Load="False"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Description}"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}"
                                />

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />

                                </VisualStateGroup>

                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: `The members "TextAlignment" and "TextWrapping" are not recognised or are not accessible?`

Comment: Above is the Textbox style in version 1903, could you tell your app's target version?

Comment: 1903 also but why are you using a TextBlock instead of a TextBox?

Comment: I will share the complete TextBox style for you.

Comment: How about simply using a string resource for the placeholder? Microsoft hasn't mentioned this anywhere in their tutorials.

Comment: you could make  `<x:String x:Key="Placeholder">Placeholder Content</x:String>` and use StaticResource to bind above Placeholder .

Comment: I'd need to see an example of this so I'll ask a new question

Comment: Does above could solve your issue? if it works, I will post it for that case.

Comment: With the glyph yes but I also wanted to find out how without the glyph too

Comment: Yep, you could make custom  `TextBox`, and make dependency property for glyph and bind it with dependency property.